# Can the equation $\mathbf{Av}=\mathbf{b}$ be solved as $\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{b}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, vectors

Say I have a $3\times 3$ matrix called $\mathbf A$ and a column matrix vector $\mathbf v$ and another column matrix vector $\mathbf b$.

If I have the equation $\mathbf{Av}=\mathbf{b}$ where I know $\mathbf A$ and $\mathbf b$ can I solve for $\mathbf v$ by doing $\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{b}$?

Comment: If you know that $A^{-1}$ exists, sure.

Comment: As long as $A$ is invertible you can do so.

Comment: if $A^{-1}$ doesn't exist , we can use $A^-$ which is the solution of $AXA=A$(solution may not be unique) , $Av=b\Leftrightarrow v=A^-b$

Answer (score 1):

If $Av=b$ and $A$ is invertible, then $v=A^{-1}b$. But even if $A^{-1}$ exists, calculating it might be a cumbersome task. In general, the problem of finding $v$ is the same as solving a linear system of equations. You don't need to calculate $A^{-1}$ to find $v$. There are several [methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#Solving_a_linear_system) to do so, including for cases when $A$ is *not* invertible.

An interesting example: in MATLAB, instead of calculating $v$ by typing `v = inv(A)*b` (it means "calculate $A^{-1}$ and then multiply it by $b$"), you should always type `v = A\b` (it means "solve $Av=b$, without necessarily calculating $A^{-1}$"). The later code is usually much faster.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that there may be  a solution even if A is not invertiable, the Matlab code example try to find such a solution